LLM using Llama 3.1 and Streamlit not ready code file properly
I have this python code that initializes a Streamlit session and, powered by Llama 3.1, implements a good-practices for programming languages such as Python, SQL and C#. Asks for a code file first and then starts reading the content on the file and should return a full guide of recommendations to implement in the code but this is the part where it fails because it seems like Llama 3.1 is not reading the content. Here´s the code:
import streamlit as st
from llama_index import ServiceContext, Document, set_global_service_context 
from llama_index.indices.vector_store.base import VectorStoreIndex
from llama_index.llms import Ollama
from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader
from pathlib import Path
from llama_index.memory import ChatMemoryBuffer
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

# --------------- Interfaz superior ------------------------------------------
st.header("Chatea con los documentos de información SOP  .")

# Para cada sección una historia diferente
if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.messages = [
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "¡Hazme una pregunta sobre los documentos PDF que me diste!"}
    ]

# Inicializa la memoria si no existe en la sesión
if "memory" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.memory = ChatMemoryBuffer.from_defaults()

# --------------- LLM ------------------------------------------
prompt_custom = (
    """
    Eres un chatbot experto en buenas prácticas de los lenguajes de programación: Python, SQL y C#. Eres experto en las guías de estilos que se te proporcionaron 
    en los documentos PDF, conoces la sintaxis correcta y la adecuada definición de clases, funciones y variables y la forma adecuada de agregar
    comentarios. Para cada respuesta debes de indicar recomendaciones o sugerencias de cambios que se le puedan realizar al código para que 
    cumpla con la guía de estilos. Sé cordial y específico. Responde en español. 
    """
)

@st.cache_resource(show_spinner=False)
def load_data():
    with st.spinner(text="¡La carga e indexación de los documentos a Streamlit no se detiene! Esto debería tomar entre 1 y 2 minutos."):
        reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(input_dir="./styleGuide", recursive=True)  # Ruta de los documentos
        docs = []
        for file_path in Path("./styleGuide").rglob("*.pdf"):
            pdf_path = str(file_path)
            document_name = file_path.name
            pdf_reader = PdfReader(pdf_path)
            num_pages = len(pdf_reader.pages)
            for page_num in range(num_pages):
                page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
                text = page.extract_text()
                if text:
                    # Crear un documento con texto y metadatos
                    doc = Document(
                        text=text,
                        metadata={"document_name": document_name, "page_number": page_num + 1}
                    )
                    docs.append(doc)

        service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
            llm=Ollama(
                model="llama3.1:8b-instruct-q8_0",
                request_timeout=1500.0,
                temperature=0,
                system_prompt=prompt_custom,
                max_tokens=125000
            ),
            embed_model='local'
        )
        set_global_service_context(service_context)
        index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(docs, service_context=service_context)
        return index

# Cargar los datos e inicializar el índice
index = load_data()

# Usar la memoria de la sesión para el chat engine
memory = st.session_state.memory
chat_engine = index.as_chat_engine(chat_mode="context", verbose=True, memory=memory)

# ------------ front end -----------------
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Carga tu archivo Python (.py) o SQL (.sql) para revisión", type=['py', 'sql', 'cs'])

if uploaded_file is not None:
    content = uploaded_file.read().decode("utf-8")
    
    st.write("### Contenido del Archivo:")
    st.write(content)
    
    if not content:
        st.error("El archivo no se pudo leer correctamente.")
        
    doc = None
    
    if uploaded_file.name.endswith(".py"):
        # Leer el archivo .py
        # content = uploaded_file.read().decode("utf-8")  # Leer y decodificar el archivo .py
        doc = Document(
            text=content,
            metadata={"document_name": uploaded_file.name, "file_type": "python"}
        )

    elif uploaded_file.name.endswith(".sql"):
        # content = uploaded_file.read().decode("utf-8")
        doc = Document(
            text=content,
            metadata={"document_name": uploaded_file.name, "file_type": "sql"}
        )
        
    if uploaded_file.name.endswith(".cs"):
        # content = uploaded_file.read().decode("utf-8")
        doc = Document(
            text=content,
            metadata={"document_name": uploaded_file.name, "file_type": "csharp"}
        )
        
    if doc is not None:
        st.write("### Insertando el archivo en el índice:")
        st.write(doc)

        # Añadir el archivo al índice temporalmente para que el LLM lo procese
        index.insert(doc)

        # Pedirle al chat engine que haga la revisión del código según la guía de estilo
        with st.spinner("Revisando el código según la guía de estilos..."):
            response = chat_engine.chat(f"Revisa el archivo {uploaded_file.name} y sugiere mejoras según la guía de estilos.")
        
        # Mostrar las sugerencias
        st.write("### Revisión automática del código:")
        st.write(response.response)

The output looks like this:

For non english speakers, what it sais, basically, is that it has not access to the code in the file "Users.sql", but i get the same output everytime, I dont know what could be happening. Any help will be welcomed, thanks in advance :)
